# deployed asp.net project white screen

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I have deployed my asp.net webform project in my computer (localhost). I published it (FileSystem). But when I run the browser , it's only white screen. . .
My O.S is windows 8, Visual studio used is vs 2013.
I wonder what went wrong. . .thanks for any help.

I already did registering the aspnet 4.0 vis cmd in administrator mode and yet can't see aspnet 4.0 in application pool

Please see screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you a) given the site a hostname in IIS and b) added an entry to it in your /system32/drivers/etc/hosts file to point that name to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: site name? I named it taguigstake. for b.) I don't know how to do that. . .

Comment: No not the site name in VS, the *host* name in IIS - go to the site in IIS, click "Bindings" and if the 'Host Name' field is not 'taguigstake' then edit the entry and change the host name. Once you've done that, use an elevated Notepad to open c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (there is no file extension for the hosts file) and add a line at the end that looks like      *127.0.0.1 taguigstake* (use the others as a reference). When you save that, the site will be available at `http://taguigstake/` (not `http://localhost/taguigstake` )

Comment: done but it has error, site name can't be reached. . . ahmm can you teach me the step by step process on how to deploy on local computer vis FileSystem in publish? I just followed the tutorial I've got but it's not working.

Comment: Happy to help, but so we don't pollute this thread I've added my twitter feed to my profile. Go post something on it and we'll sort something out.